# Code Runs in Jupyter Notebook but not Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, linear-regression

I'm running a script to perform a linear regression using scikit-learn. In jupyter notebook it ran fine, but having converted to a .py file it now gives me an error. The line of code in question is:

```
self.reg = linear_model.LinearRegression().fit(self.train_data, self.train_target)
```

Have checked that the inputs are correct - both arrays of the correct shape and correct data types.

The error is:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

And occasionally the following:

```
XXX lineno: 459, opcode: 32
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "learn.py", line 175, in <module>
    run_learn(42,0.3)
  File "learn.py", line 171, in run_learn
    learn_object.assess_performance()
  File "learn.py", line 108, in assess_performance
self.score = self.reg.score(self.train_data, self.train_target)
  File "/Users/[usr]/environments/tf_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 408, in score
    y_pred = self.predict(X)
  File "/Users/[usr]/environments/tf_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py", line 221, in
 predict
    return self._decision_function(X)
  File "/Users/[usr]/environments/tf_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py", line 204, in
 _decision_function
    X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=['csr', 'csc', 'coo'])
  File "/Users/[usr]/environments/tf_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 459, in
check_array
    if isinstance(dtype, (list, tuple)):
SystemError: unknown opcode
```

I can't think why something would run fine in jupyter notebook but not in python .. any ideas?

** Having been asked about checking the Python version, both usages have occurred within a virtual environment running Python 3.6 (for compatibility with other modules)

Comment: Check the python version of both environments.

Comment: paste more code to find the problem.

Comment: Are you sure you're using Python 3.6 in both environments. It looks like you're using Python 3.8 when running the .py file. Incompatible versions causes these kind of errors.